# gstreamer pipeline to opencv

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

I have a gstreamer pipline streaming from my raspberry pi:

```
rpicamsrc bitrate=5000000 ! queue ! h264parse !  rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=192.168.xxx.xxx port=xxxx
```

This pipe streams h264 data to a receiver using TCP. I want the receiving end to do two things:

relay the information onscreen:
using something like:

```
gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc host=192.168.xxx.xxx port=xxxx ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false text-overlay=false
```

I also want to use openCV to extract and manipulate the frames. What would be the easiest way to do this? My idea is to use tee on the sender to give two outputs and have my receiver get one of the outputs and the openCV to get another. Are there any better ways to do this? Should I just tee two tcp (or udp) sinks? Should I use an appsink?

I would prefer to use cv2 on my server who is sending the video to a client. Server should capture frames from camera and 1) transmit to client and 2) manipulate frames via CV2